# How to calculate the base current of the transistors in this voltage regulator?

Tags: transistors, resistors, diodes, voltage-regulator, zener

I arbitrarily chose the resistors value and tried calculating the base currents.

On Q5 base resistors I tried thevenin, but it didn't work. The values weren't the same as the simulation.

And in regards to Q4 i have no idea on where to start.

[image: Voltage regulator]

Comment: Can you show your work? What voltages are you assuming, component values, Thevenin calculation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to do a DC analysis is going to be difficult because there are active devices and feedback involved.

The base current is going to be whatever it takes to cause the current through the load to be enough to keep the voltage at the regulated value, and this is going to depend on the pass transistor's beta.

As an example here is the circuit with a 2N3055, in the model beta forward (BF) is set to 73. This is roughly the gain at low currents, as the collector current increases, beta decreases. By the time \$I_C\$ gets to 10 A the gain is pretty low.
[image: regulator base current schematic]

The graphs show the collector current, base current and ratio of collector to base current as the load is swept from 1 mA to 10 A.
[image: regulator base current graphs]

So you can see the base current is highly dependent on the load current and the transistor gain which itself is dependent on the load current. You might be able to figure that out with a circuit analysis but it's much easier to just simulate or prototype and measure.